# Open pdf in web browser in C# console application

Tags: c#, pdf, console-application, windows

**Requirement:** 
I have a pdf file in my machine. Using console\windows application, i need to open that pdf file from browser itself. I am getting answers to open pdf file in browser using ASP.NET. But i need answer to open pdf in browser using console app.

**I tried the below code:**

```
string localURL = @"C:\MyLocation\apllication demo.pdf";
System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser webbrowser = new System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser();
webbrowser.Navigate(localURL);
```

But no use. It asusual opening in its default application.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply because you are supplying a wrong path.

For browser, the path would look like this:

```
string localURL = "file:///C:/MyLocation/apllication%20demo.pdf"
```

Note that `%20` is a space character,so perhaps use `string.Replace(" ","%20")` when building the Url.

Comment: This opens a SaveFileDialog not the PDF on the web browser control.